# ufunc 'add' did not contain loop with signature matching type dtype ('S32') ('S32') ('S32')

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to run someone's script for some simulations I've made to try plotting some histograms, but when I do I always get the error message mentioned above. I have no idea what's gone wrong.

Here's the complete traceback error I get:

```
File "AVAnalyse.py", line 205, in <module> 
  f.write(line[0] + '  ' + line[1] + '  ' + line[2] + '  ' + line[3]) 
TypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('S32') dtype('S32') dtype('S32')
```

This is the code I am trying to run:

```
name_out = "histogram_" + donor + "_" + acceptor + ".dat"   
f = open(name_out, 'w')
f.write('distance  d.probability  efficiency  e.probability')
for line in dist_hist:
    f.write(line[0] + '  ' + line[1] + '  ' + line[2] + '  ' + line[3])
f.close()

print "data saved in " + "histogram_" + donor + "_" + acceptor + ".dat"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Show us the `shape` and `dtype` for `line` or `dist_hist`.  I suspect `line[0]` is an array with 'S32' dtype, not just a string element of such an array.

Comment: @hpaulj `dist_hist = zeroes((bins,4))` and is in the script 5 more times, but I'm not sure what it means here are the other times it's mentioned other than the line in the origional question `dist_hist[index_ef,3] += hist_add` `dist_hist[index,1] += hist_add` `dist_hist[:,0] = arange(mini,maxi,(maxi-mini)/(float(bins)-0.5))` `dist_hist[:,2] = arange(mine,maxe,(maxe-mine)/(float(bins)-0.5))` –

Comment: Show `print(line)`.

Comment: the `print(line)` before the script stated above is `print "average distance between dyes is ", average_distance/(len(data[::step])*len(datd[::step]))` while the next line with print is in the question.    I'm sorry if I'm misunderstanding and I appreciate you trying to help!

Comment: I want to see what `line` looks like without the problematic string formatting.

Comment: I've uploaded the script [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6JBAjQjfHfpWHpVSG55cklfcVU/view?usp=sharing) hopefully this is more useful! - edit-fixed link

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It seems like `line[0]`, `line[1]`, `line[2]`, `line[3]` are elements of `dist_hist`. `dict_hist` is a `numpy.ndarray`. The elements of `dict_hist` has a numeric type (like `np.float64`) (based on calculations from your attached file). You're trying to add elements of different types: `np.float64` and `str`. If you want to avoid this `TypeError`, you can change type of `line[0]`, `line[1]`, `line[2]`, `line[3]` to str.

Your snippet of code should be like this:

```
name_out = "histogram_"+donor+"_"+acceptor+".dat"   
f = open(name_out,'w')
f.write('distance  d.probability  efficiency  e.probability')
for line in dist_hist:
  f.write(str(line[0])+'  '+str(line[1])+'  '+str(line[2])+'  '+str(line[3]))
f.close()

print "data saved in " +"histogram_"+donor+"_"+acceptor+".dat"
```

EDIT:

You should replace this snippet of code:

```
name_out = "histogram_"+donor+"_"+acceptor+".dat"   
f = open(name_out,'w')
f.write('distance  d.probability  efficiency  e.probability')
for line in dist_hist:
  f.write(line[0]+'  '+line[1]+'  '+line[2]+'  '+line[3])
f.close()
```

to this one:

```
name_out = "histogram_" + donor + "_" + acceptor + ".dat"   
f = open(name_out,'w')
f.write('distance  d.probability  efficiency  e.probability\n')
for line in dist_hist:
  f.write(str(line[0]) + '  ' + str(line[1]) + '  ' + str(line[2]) + '  ' + str(line[3]) + '\n')
f.close()
```

Before that, strings were written to file in one line. Because of that your data variable point to empty array since we start to read from 2nd line (which was empty).

Answer (score 0):

My problem was solved by @Eduard Ilyasov's solution. The TLDR is to wrap the part where the error came from in `str(thing)` (when printing for me).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

My best advice when you're facing an error like that. Typically you have to check the type compatibility of your data. Take few minutes to check it, print it and you should find an incompatibility. Often, that's mixed of string and numerical values.