# UFuncTypeError dtype u32

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, bigdata, conv-neural-network

Nodule Identification Model

This model takes a small volume (chunk) from a lung scan (3D image) as input and classifies the chunk into two classes:

```
Class 0 : Chunk does not contain a nodule
Class 1 : Chunk contains a nodule
```

I had this error in this part:UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype(' dtype('

def get_validation_batch(validation_x_ids, validation_y, batch_number):
        num_images = len(validation_x_ids)

```
    count = 0
    start_index = batch_number * FLAGS.batch_size
    end_index = start_index + FLAGS.batch_size
    end_index = num_images if end_index > num_images else end_index
    real_batch_size = end_index - start_index

    validation_x = np.ndarray([real_batch_size, FLAGS.chunk_size, FLAGS.chunk_size, FLAGS.chunk_size, 1], dtype=np.float32)

    for chunk_id in validation_x_ids[start_index : end_index]:
        chunk = np.load(DATA_PATH + chunk_id + '_X.npy').astype(np.float32, copy=False)
        validation_x[count, :, :, :, :] = img_to_rgb(chunk)
        count = count + 1

    return validation_x, validation_y[start_index : end_index]
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to a datatype mismatch in string concatenation in `np.load(...)` statement where `chund_id` is an integer obtained from a `np.ndarray()` while `'_X.npy'` is a string.

Hence, replace the line `chunk = np.load(DATA_PATH + chunk_id + '_X.npy').astype(np.float32, copy=False)` with the below line:

```
chunk = np.load(DATA_PATH + str(chunk_id) + '_X.npy').astype(np.float32, copy=False)
```

typecasting `chunk_id` with `str()` before adding with other strings.

References:

- [Python: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('S21') dtype('S21') dtype('S21')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44527956/python-ufunc-add-did-not-contain-a-loop-with-signature-matching-types-dtype)
- [ufunc 'add' did not contain loop with signature matching type dtype ('S32') ('S32') ('S32')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41859824/ufunc-add-did-not-contain-loop-with-signature-matching-type-dtype-s32-s3/41938591)

Comment: OSError: [Errno 36] File name too long: '/content/luna_preprocessing_2/[[[[0.]\n   [0.]\n   [0.]\n   ...\n   [0.]\n   [0.]\n   [0.]]\n\n  [[0.]\n   [0.]\n   [0.]\n   ...\n   [0.]\n

Comment: Seems `chunk_id` isn't a integer and could be an object. Could you print `type(chunk_id)` and check its exact type?

Comment: the type of chunk_id is

Comment: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>